# Installing Swampy module onto Python

Tags: python

I need to install a package for my Python interpretor.

It is called swampy and you can get info from the web page -

http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/swampy/install.html

I am a novice so if you can provide step by step instructions please.

Answer (score 3):

### Using PIP to install swampy

pip is a tool for installing and managing Python packages

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install swampy
```